# saving image in sqlite db using a save button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, import

I'm a newbie in developing an android app and I am currently developing cooking application. I want to add a new recipe to my db with recipe name, ingredients, procedures, category, notes and photo. But the problem is when I add photo from camera or gallery, it stop working and I want to view the image taken to an imageview and save it to db using a save button. But please help me. I don't know what to do with my project.

```
MY DBAdapter

package com.elasandesu.quickeasykitchenv3;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;


// TO USE:
// Change the package (at top) to match your project.
// Search for "TODO", and make the appropriate changes.
public class DBAdapter {

    // DB Fields
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
    /*
     * CHANGE 1:
     */
    // TODO: Setup your fields here:

    public static final String KEY_RNAME = "rname";
    public static final String KEY_RCAT = "rcat";
    public static final String KEY_RING = "ring";
    public static final String KEY_RSTEPS = "rsteps";
    public static final String KEY_RNOTE = "rnote";
    public static final String KEY_RPHOTO = "rphoto";
    //public static final String KEY_RPHOTONME = "rphotornme";

    // TODO: Setup your field numbers here (0 = KEY_ROWID, 1=...)
    public static final int COL_RNAME = 1;
    public static final int COL_RCAT = 2;
    public static final int COL_RING = 3;
    public static final int COL_RSTEPS = 4;
    public static final int COL_RNOTE = 5;
    public static final int COL_RPHOTO = 6;
    //public static final int COL_RPHOTONME =7;

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_RNAME, KEY_RCAT, KEY_RING, KEY_RSTEPS, KEY_RNOTE, KEY_RPHOTO};

    // DB info: it's name, and the table we are using (just one).


    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Quick.sqlite";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "recipe";
    // Track DB version if a new version of your app changes the format.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;   

    // Context of application who uses us.
    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Public methods:
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_RECIPE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
                + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_RNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RCAT + " TEXT," + KEY_RING+ " TEXT," + KEY_RSTEPS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RNOTE + " TEXT," + KEY_RPHOTO + " BLOB" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RECIPE_TABLE);
    }

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    }

    // Open the database connection.
    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // Close the database connection.
    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // Add a new set of values to the database.
    public long insertRow(String rName, String rCat, String rIng, String rSteps, String rNote) {//byte[] rPhoto
        /*
         * CHANGE 3:
         */     
        // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
        // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
        // Create row's data:
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_RNAME, rName);
        initialValues.put(KEY_RCAT, rCat);
        initialValues.put(KEY_RING, rIng);
        initialValues.put(KEY_RSTEPS, rSteps);
        initialValues.put(KEY_RNOTE, rNote);
        //initialValues.put(KEY_RPHOTO, rPhoto);
        //initialValues.put(KEY_RPHOTONME, rPhotonme);
        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    // Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
    public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;

    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        Cursor c = getAllRows();
        long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }

    // Return all data in the database.
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                            where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
    //Get specific row by category
    public Cursor getCateg (String categ)  throws SQLException {
        String where =  "SELECT * FROM recipe where rcat=\""+categ+"\"";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(where, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;  
    }
    //KEY_RCAT + " = \'" + categ + " \'";
    //"select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null
    // Get a specific row (by rowId)
    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {

        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
    public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String rName, String rCat, String rIng, String rSteps, String rNote) {//byte[] rPhoto
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

        /*
         * CHANGE 4:
         */
        // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
        // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
        // Create row's data:
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_RNAME, rName);
        newValues.put(KEY_RCAT, rCat);
        newValues.put(KEY_RING, rIng);
        newValues.put(KEY_RSTEPS, rSteps);
        newValues.put(KEY_RNOTE, rNote);
        //newValues.put(KEY_RPHOTO, rPhoto);
        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
    }



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Private Helper Classes:
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Private class which handles database creation and upgrading.
     * Used to handle low-level database access.
     */
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper
    {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        }

}






Activity Code 

package com.elasandesu.quickeasykitchenv3;



import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Addrecipe extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    String[] cat = {"BEEF","CHICKEN",
            "PORK", "FISH", "VEGETABLES"};
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    String DB_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Quick.sqlite";
    String TABLE_NAME = "recipe"; 

    ImageView recphoto;
    DBAdapter db;
    EditText recname, recing, recsteps, recnote;
    Spinner spinner1;
    TextView category;
    Button save, reset, upload;


    public static String rcat = " ";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addrecipe);
        category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categorytxtview);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categorysp);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cat);
         adapter_state
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_state);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetbtn);
        recname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recipename);
        recing = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ingredient);
        recnote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
        recsteps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.procedure);
        recphoto= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        openDB();


    final String[] option = new String[] { "Take from Camera", "Select from Gallery" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Option");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Selected Item", String.valueOf(which));
            if (which == 0) {
                callCamera();
            }
            if (which == 1) {
                callGallery();
            }
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadbtn);
    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    });


    }

    //insert activity here :D

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_REQUEST:
            Bundle extras= data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                selectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                recphoto.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                Intent i = new Intent(Addrecipe.this,
                        Addrecipe.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

            break;
        case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
            Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();

            if (extras2 != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                recphoto.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                Intent i = new Intent(Addrecipe.this,
                        Addrecipe.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();           
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }





    /**
     * open camera method
     */
    public void callCamera() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cameraIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

    }

    /**
     * open gallery method
     */

    public void callGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    }






    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  
        closeDB();
    }

    private void openDB() {
        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
    }

    private void closeDB() {
        db.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spinner1.setSelection(position);
}

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void saveHasBeenClicked (View v) {
        String rName = recname.getText().toString();
        String rIng = recing.getText().toString();
        String rSteps =recsteps.getText().toString();
        String rNote = recnote.getText().toString();
        String rCat =  (String) spinner1.getSelectedItem();
        long newId = db.insertRow(rName,"\n"+ rCat," \n "+ rIng," \n" + rSteps, rNote);
        Cursor cursor = db.getRow(newId);
        displayRecordSet(cursor);

        Intent evilIntent = new Intent(Addrecipe.this, Selected.class);
        startActivity(evilIntent);  
            }

    public void onClick_ClearAll(View v) {
        db.deleteAll();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cleared ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    // Display an entire record set to the screen.
            private void displayRecordSet(Cursor cursor) {
                String message = "";
                // populate the message from the cursor
                // Reset cursor to start, checking to see if there's data:
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        // Process the data:
                        int id = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID);
                        String rName = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_RNAME);
                        String rCat = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_RCAT);
                        String rIng = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_RING);
                        String rSteps = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_RSTEPS);
                        String rNote = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_RNOTE);



                        // Append data to the message:
                        message += "id=" + id
                                   +", Recipe Name : " + rName
                                   +", Category :  " + rCat
                                   +", Ingredients : " + rIng
                                   +", Procedure:  " + rSteps
                                   +", Note: " + rNote
                                   +"\n";
                    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Save Has Been Clicked "+ message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // Close the cursor to avoid a resource leak.
                cursor.close();

            }
    }

 And the XML file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/nb"
    android:onClick="displayClicked"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1462dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/recipename"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/recipenametxtview"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recipenametxtview"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Type the Recipe Name"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categorytxtview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recipenametxtview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recipename"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="Category:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ingtxtview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/categorytxtview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/categorysp"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:text="Ingredients:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/categorysp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recipename"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/recipename"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/categorytxtview" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notetxtview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/proceduretxtview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/proceduretxtview"
            android:layout_marginTop="253dp"
            android:text="Note:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ingredient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ingtxtview"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/categorysp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ingtxtview"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Type Here the Ingredients : e.g. 1 kilo of Flour"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="false"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/procedure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/proceduretxtview"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ingredient"
            android:layout_below="@+id/proceduretxtview"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Type in this format 1.) procedure 1 [newline] 2.) procedure 2"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/notetxtview"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/procedure"
            android:layout_below="@+id/notetxtview"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Includes information, cautions and other health information"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipenametxtview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/itemRname"
            android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
            android:text="Recipe Name:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phototxtview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/note"
            android:layout_below="@+id/note"
            android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
            android:text="Photo:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/proceduretxtview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ingredient"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ingredient"
            android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
            android:text="Procedure:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/uploadbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/phototxtview"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phototxtview"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ingtxtview"
            android:text="Upload Photo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/uploadbtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/savebtn"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/savebtn"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/note"
            android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
            android:onClick="onClick_ClearAll()"
            android:text="Reset" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/savebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/uploadbtn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:onClick="saveHasBeenClicked"
            android:text="Save" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

please help me.. it will be a great help.
```

Comment: At which moment does 'it stop working'? What do you mean exactly with 'not working'?

Comment: What does your logcat say about "it stop working " ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It stop working when I take image either from camera or gallery. First, after I take picture form either of the two, it should be appear first in the imageview i declare in xml before I will save it but unfortunately it does'nt